# htlatex breaks down when using siunitx

Tags: siunitx, catcodes, htlatex

I have a manuscript that is written in LaTeX. After a couple of rejections and modifications, the new journal seems to only accept .docx files. I plan to convert my manuscript to a .odt as the editor is happy to work with that format.

Here is a small, non-minimal, but self-contained document (Test.tex) I am trying to convert:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\title{Germination of Avocado using special germination media}
\author{E.Sandoval \thanks{e.san@uum.ac.ij}}
\usepackage[mode=text]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\iffalse
\begin{abstract}
Avocado seeds from Guatemala were sterilised and de-hulled incubated in DBB special salt media. Three controls were employed. As first control, de-hulled seeds were germinated in saline. As second control, the seeds were were modified and were incubated in DBB media. As the third control, the unmodified seeds were incubated in saline.\par
Germination with de-hulled DBB media took 5 days, de-hulled and saline took 12 days, unmodified and DBB took 15 days, and unmodified with saline took 16 days.\par
This suggests that rapid germination can be achieved with the new DBB media.
\end{abstract}

\newpage

\section{Introduction}
This is going to be a long introduction about something. I think it would be very interesting to write about other studies on Avocado germination and what they found. Explain why you want to investigate this in context of previous studies and the specific problem you are addressing.\par
\fi
Seeds were incubated in \qty{23.06}{\milli\litre} of media.\par
\end{document}
```

I am using the command: `htlatex Test.tex "xhtml,ooffice" "ooffice/! -cmozhtf" "-coo -cvalidate"`

In the code above, the part between `\iffalse` and `\fi` is just text and that converts nicely into a .odt file without any hiccups in previous test runs. However, errors begin to pop up when I try and use the `siunitx` package. and add the line `Seeds were incubated in \qty{23.06}{\milli\litre} of media.`

I get the error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   ^
l.35 \catcode`\^^
                 A=\catcode`\%
? 
! Emergency stop.
<to be read again> 
                   ^
l.35 \catcode`\^^
                 A=\catcode`\%
Output written on Test.dvi (53 pages, 15472 bytes).
Transcript written on Test.log.
```

The corresponding `Test.log` file is massive and really couldn't find anything informative (at least to my untrained eyes).

I am not trying to be thick here, but there don't seem to be nice resources for writing writing a .cfg file. All examples here seem to go right over my head!

Comment: Why such a complicated MWE when you get the same error with `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
foo
\end{document}
`

Comment: @daleif: To show that there was nothing wrong in the text I was typing. LIke the introduction of some other half-space or catcode. Sorry.

Comment: It is always best (and is an important debugging tool) to provide the smallest MWE and then we don't have check interactions for irrelevant things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, don't use `htlatex`, it is deprecated,  use `make4ht` instead. It is important especially for the ODT output, because it does various post-processing tasks that are necessary to get valid ODT file.

Regarding the bug, it seems to be caused by this line in `siunitx.sty`:

```
 \AtBeginDocument { \RequirePackage { color } }
```

It causes some catcode issues in the processing of TeX4ht configuration files. To fix that, we can load the Color package earlier, for example using this config file:

```
\RequirePackage{color} 
\Preamble{xhtml}

\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

You can compile your example using this command:

```
$ make4ht -c config.cfg -f odt Test.tex
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: This works very well Thank you. Would you know how to include uncertainties as well? I am getting errors with \num{26.0(3)e7}.

Comment: @Miloop do you use up-to-date TeX Live? I don't get errors with `\num{26.0(3)e7}`, so maybe it is something that was fixed in the meantime.

Comment: I am on a linux mint. I am running pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023).

Comment: @Miloop that doesn't look old. Do you get compilation errors, or errors when you open the ODT file?

Comment: I get the error: `[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex  58  Missing $ inserted.` in the terminal. It does result in an odt. But the numbers are not rendered correctly at all. It is mostly missing. Also, why does it say `htlatex` when I ran the `make4ht` command ?

Comment: @Miloop ah, I get an error with your other MWE for the `\num` command. It seems that the `tight-spacing=true` option of Siunitx is the problem.

Comment: I've addressed the `color` business in https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/commit/5fd624dd4f07684fec1e040e28d44ebbb1ab05d7 - I'll look at the more recent issue too and see what interface changes may be needed

Comment: @JosephWright thanks