# How to use make4ht for threeparttable with siunitx to make an odt

Tags: siunitx, threeparttable, make4ht

I am trying to work off my previous request here: [htlatex breaks down when using siunitx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/707416/htlatex-breaks-down-when-using-siunitx)

For context, I am trying to convert a manuscript written in .tex into a .odt file using `make4ht`. I am using Linux Mint and pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023).

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=2.0cm, left=1.0cm, right=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
%\renewcommand*{\Authfont}{\raggedright}
\renewcommand*{\Affilfont}{\normalsize\raggedright}

\usepackage{booktabs}                           %For \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}                      %For a more structured tables
\AtBeginEnvironment{tablenotes}{\scriptsize}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=justified,
singlelinecheck=false,format=hang}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\title{Germination of Avocado using special germination media}
\author[1]{Ermando Sandoval}
\affil[1]{University of Glastoc, Mirano Institute}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{mode=text}
\sisetup{range-units = single}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty}
\sisetup{inter-unit-product=\textperiodcentered}
\sisetup{open-bracket=\, ,
                close-bracket=\,}
\sisetup{tight-spacing=true}
\sisetup{print-unity-mantissa=false}
\sisetup{retain-zero-uncertainty=true}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty-units=single}
\sisetup{group-separator = {,}}
\DeclareSIUnit\cells{cells}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
There are \qty{3.25(2)e12}{\cells\per\milli\litre} in this sample.

The results are provided in Table \ref{Tab1} below.

\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{This is a test table. Let's see how this renders in the odt.} \label{Tab1}
\begin{tabular}{l l S S c S S}
\toprule
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Groups}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Compounds}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Potential}} & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Discovery}}\\
\cline{3-4} \cline{6-7}
 & & \textbf{Perm} & \textbf{Tab} & & \textbf{Perm} & \textbf{Tab} \\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{Amines} & methylamine& 16.5(2) & 18.6(26) & & 49 & 62.1(2)\\
 & ethylamine &6.5\tnote{a} & {N/A} & & 0.2(0) & 0.6(1)\\
 & tert-butyl amine&15.6 & 88 & & 55.5(156) & 26\\
 \midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{Salts} & \ce{NaCl} & 99.6(2) & {N/A} & & 12 & 16.8(15)\\
  & \ce{CaCO3} & 6.5(1) & {N/A} & & 15 & 19.2(35)\\
   & \ce{(NH4)2SO4}& 16.2(16) & {N/A} & & 49 & 69.6(12)\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[a] Significantly low.
\item N/A = sample loss
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

When I execute this, it provide me with this output in pdf:

[image: Correct_output]

I tried to get a .odt file using the command: `make4ht -c config.cfg -f odt Test.tex`, where the `config.cfg` contains:

```
\RequirePackage{color} 
\Preamble{xhtml}

\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

but get this output in the .odt file:

[image: Odt_output]

In the normal text, the uncertainty appears as a pasted text and the exponent do not appear correctly. The caption, tablenotes and the content of the table is also lost.

On the terminal, I get this output:

```
[STATUS]  make4ht: Conversion started
[STATUS]  make4ht: Input file: Test.tex
[ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
[ERROR]   htlatex: Filename Line    Message
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   75   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   75   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   88   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   88   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   88   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   88   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   89   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   89   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   89   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   89   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   90   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   90   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   90   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   90   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   92   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   92   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   93   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   93   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   93   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   93   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   94   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   94   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   94   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   94   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   95   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   95   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
[ERROR]   htlatex: Filename Line    Message
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   75   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   75   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   88   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   88   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   88   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   88   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   89   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   89   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   89   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   89   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   90   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   90   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   90   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   90   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   92   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   92   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   93   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   93   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   93   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   93   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   94   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   94   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   94   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   94   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   95   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   95   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
[ERROR]   htlatex: Filename Line    Message
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   75   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   75   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   88   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   88   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   88   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   88   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   89   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   89   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   89   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   89   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   90   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   90   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   90   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   90   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   92   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   92   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   93   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   93   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   93   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   93   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   94   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   94   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   94   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   94   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   95   Missing $ inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./Test.tex   95   Missing $ inserted.
[STATUS]  make4ht: Conversion finished
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several issues in TeX4ht need to be fixed to get this to work.

First, there are two issues with the Siunitx support. One is that the `tight-spacing` option causes compilation errors, the other is caused by the `S` columns in your tabular, because  it caused the table to be complete mess. Both of these issues can be fixed using this configuration file, `siunitx.4ht`:

```
% siunitx.4ht (2024-01-22-12:04), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 2021-2024 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2024-01-22-12:04}

\RequirePackage{color}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__siunitx_angle_arc_print_auxv_fourht:w
  #1 \q_nil #2 \q_nil #3 \q_nil #4 \q_nil #5 \q_nil #6 \q_stop
{\bgroup\siunitx_print_number:n {#1#2#3#4#5}\egroup}

\HLet\__siunitx_angle_arc_print_auxv:w\__siunitx_angle_arc_print_auxv_fourht:w


\cs_set_protected:Npn \__siunitx_angle_arc_print_auxvi_fourht:n #1
{
  % we need to define these commands here
  \def\degree{\ht:special{t4ht@+&{35}x2218;}x}
  \def\arcminute{\prime}
  \def\arcsecond{\prime\prime}
  \ensuremath{\NoFonts\sp{#1}\EndNoFonts}
}

\HLet\__siunitx_angle_arc_print_auxvi:n\__siunitx_angle_arc_print_auxvi_fourht:n

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/707485/2891
\bool_set_false:N \l__siunitx_number_tight_bool

% disable S columns for tables
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/707485/2891
\cs_set_protected:Npn \siunitx_cell_begin:w {}
\cs_set_protected:Npn \siunitx_cell_end: {}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\Hinput{siunitx}
\endinput
```

There is also another problem, with the `mhchem` package. It distributes it's  own config file, `mhchem.4ht`, which has hardcoded HTML elements. Because of this, chemical elements are not shown in the ODT output. This version of `mhchem.4ht` should fix that:

```
%% mhchem.4ht
%% 2021-12-31
%% Copyright 2015-2021 Martin Hensel
%
%% This file is part of the mhchem bundle for LaTeX
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License version 1.3c
% which is included as lppl-1-3c.txt.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
% The Current Maintainer of this work is Martin Hensel.
%
% ( In order to fight spam, the maintainer's contact      )
% ( information is "encrypted" with ROT13.                )
% ( If you do not know ROT13 yet and have no tool for     )
% ( decryption, simply do an Internet search for "ROT13". )
%
% ,---[ ROT 13 ]---
% | Gur Pheerag Znvagnvare bs guvf jbex vf Znegva Urafry
% |   jub pna or pbagnpgrq ivn
% |     zupurz@ZnegvaUrafry.qr
% |   be ivn znvy
% |     Znegva Urafry
% |     Cbfgfge. 20
% |     09232 Unegznaafqbes
% |     Treznal
% `----------
%
% This work consists of all files listed in manifest.txt.
%
%
\ExplSyntaxOn

\Css
  { 
    .mhchem ~ .mhchem-cf { white-space: nowrap; }
    .mhchem ~ .mhchem-isotope { font-size: 0.65em; line-height: 1; display: inline-block; vertical-align: sub; text-align: right; }
    .mhchem ~ .mhchem-supsub  { font-size: 0.65em; line-height: 1; display: inline-block; vertical-align: sub; }
    .mhchem ~ .mhchem-sup     { font-size: 0.65em; line-height: 1; display: inline-block; vertical-align: 68\%; }
    .mhchem ~ .mhchem-sub     { font-size: 0.65em; line-height: 1; display: inline-block; vertical-align: sub; }
    .mhchem ~ .mhchem-rlap { display: inline-block; width: 0; }
    .mhchem ~ .mhchem-bond-half-top    { vertical-align: 60\%; }
    .mhchem ~ .mhchem-bond-half-middle { vertical-align: 35\%; }
    .mhchem ~ .mhchem-bond-top         { vertical-align: 20\%; }
    .mhchem ~ .mhchem-bond-bottom      { vertical-align: -20\%; }
    .mhchem ~ .mhchem-arrow { display: inline-flex; flex-direction: column; vertical-align: middle; }
    .mhchem ~ .mhchem-arrow > span { line-height: 80\%; text-align: center; }
    .mhchem ~ .mhchem-arrow > .mhchem-above { min-height: 1em; font-size: 60\%; }
    .mhchem ~ .mhchem-arrow > .mhchem-below { min-height: 1em; font-size: 60\%; }
    .mhchem ~ .mhchem-arrow > span.mhchem-arrow-normal { line-height: 40\%; }
    .mhchem ~ .mhchem-arrow > span.mhchem-arrow-larger { line-height: 25\%; font-size: 150\%; }
    .mhchem ~ .mhchem-arrow > span.mhchem-arrow-complement { line-height: 25\%; }
  }

% basic mhchem containers
\NewConfigure{mhchemce}{2}
\NewConfigure{mhchemcf}{2}

\pend:def\__mhchem_output_begin_ce:{\a:mhchemce}
\append:def\__mhchem_output_end_ce:{\b:mhchemce}
\pend:def\__mhchem_output_begin_cf:{\a:mhchemcf}
\append:def\__mhchem_output_end_cf:{\b:mhchemcf}

\Configure{mhchemcf}{\HCode{<span~class="mhchem">}}{\HCode{</span>}}
\Configure{mhchemce}{\HCode{<span~class="mhchem">}}{\HCode{</span>}}


% alternative version of coreFivd

\NewConfigure{mhchemisotope}{3}
\Configure{mhchemisotope}{\HCode{<span~class="mhchem-isotope">}}{\HCode{<br~/>&\#xfeff;}}{\HCode{</span>}}

\NewConfigure{mhchemsub}{2}
\Configure{mhchemsub}{\HCode { <sub~class="mhchem-sub"> }}{\HCode { </sub> } }

\NewConfigure{mhchemsup}{2}
\Configure{mhchemsup}{\HCode { <sup~class="mhchem-sup"> }}{\HCode { </sup> } }

\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_coreFivefourht:nnnnnnn #1#2#3#4#5#6#7
  {
    \bool_if:nT
      { \tl_if_empty_p:n {#7}  &&  ! \tl_if_empty_p:n {#5} }
      { \bool_set_true:N \l__mhchem_option_superscriptsStacked_bool }
      
    \tl_if_empty:nF {#1#2} 
      {
        \a:mhchemisotope
        \__mhchem_output_withFont:n { #1 } 
        \b:mhchemisotope
        \__mhchem_output_withFont:n { #2 }
        \c:mhchemisotope
      }
    \__mhchem_output_withFont:n { #3 } 
    \bool_if:NTF \l__mhchem_option_superscriptsStacked_bool
      {
        \tl_if_empty:nTF {#4#5#7} 
          {
            \tl_if_empty:nF {#6}
              {
                \a:mhchemsub
                \__mhchem_output_withFont:n { #6 }
                \b:mhchemsub
              }
          }
          {
            \tl_if_empty:nTF {#6}
              {
                \a:mhchemsup
                \__mhchem_output_withFont:n { #4#5#7 }
                \b:mhchemsup
              }
              { 
                \HCode { <span~class="mhchem-supsub"> }
                \__mhchem_output_withFont:n { #4#5#7 }
                \HCode { <br~/>&\#xfeff; }
                \__mhchem_output_withFont:n { #6 }
                \HCode { </span> } 
             }
          }
      }
      {
        \tl_if_empty:nF {#4}
          {
            \a:mhchemsup
            \__mhchem_output_withFont:n { #4 }
            \b:mhchemsup
          }
        \tl_if_empty:nF {#6}
          { 
            \a:mhchemsub
            \__mhchem_output_withFont:n { #6 }
            \b:mhchemsub
          }
        \tl_if_empty:nF {#5#7} 
          { 
            \a:mhchemsup
            \__mhchem_output_withFont:n { #5#7 }
            \b:mhchemsup
          }
      }
  }

% replace original coreFive with our alternative version. it will work in picture math
\HLet\__mhchem_output_coreFive:nnnnnnn\__mhchem_output_coreFivefourht:nnnnnnn

\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_withFont:n #1  %. output #1 as math or text
  {
    \bool_if:NTF \l__mhchem_output_isMathMode_bool
      { \mathrm {#1} }
      { \text {#1} }
  }

\NewConfigure{mhchemoperator}{2}
\Configure{mhchemoperator}{\HCode { <span~class="mhchem-operator"> ~ }}{\HCode { ~ </span> }}

% ideally, the following commands should be redefined using \HLet, to support picture math. 
% the current definition should work in MathML, I am not sure about normall HTML, as 
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_skipAfterAmount: { \HCode { ~ } }  % space for copy & paste
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_skipBeforeStateOfAggregation: {}
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_minus: { \HCode { &minus; } }
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_operatorPlus:
  { \a:mhchemoperator + \b:mhchemoperator  }
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_operatorMinus:
  { \a:mhchemoperator\HCode {&minus;} \b:mhchemoperator }
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_operatorEquals:
  { \a:mhchemoperator =  \b:mhchemoperator }
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_operatorPlusMinus:
  {\a:mhchemoperator \HCode {&plusmn; } \b:mhchemoperator }
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_electronDot: { \HCode { &bull; } }
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_additionCompound: { \HCode { &middot; } }
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_excited: { \HCode { &\#x2731; } }
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_commaDecimal: { , }
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_commaEnumeration: { , \HCode { &thinsp; } }
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_commaEnumerationSmall: { , \HCode { &thinsp; } }
  
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_bond_single: { \HCode { &minus; } }
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_bond_double: { \HCode { &equals; } }
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_bond_triple: { \HCode { &equiv; } }
% todo: add MathML support for these
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_bond_half:  % todo: improve
  { \HCode { <span~class="mhchem-bond-half-middle">&\#xfe4d;</span> } }
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_bond_oneAndHalf:  % todo: improve 
  { \HCode { <span~class="mhchem-rlap">&minus;</span><span~class="mhchem-bond-half-top">&\#xfe4d;</span> } }
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_bond_twoAndHalf:  % todo: improve
  { \HCode { <span~class="mhchem-rlap">=</span><span~class="mhchem-bond-half-top">&\#xfe4d;</span> } }
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_bond_twoAndHalff:  % todo: improve
  { \HCode { <span~class="mhchem-rlap~mhchem-bond-top">&minus;</span><span~class="mhchem-rlap~mhchem-bond-bottom">&minus;</span><span~class="mhchem-bond-half-middle">&\#xfe4d;</span> } }
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_bond_dotdotdot: { \HCode { &middot;&middot;&middot; } }
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_bond_dotdotdotdot: { \HCode { &middot;&middot;&middot;&middot; } }
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_bond_rightArrow: { \HCode { &\#xffeb; } }
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_bond_leftArrow: { \HCode { &\#xffe9; } }

\NewConfigure{mhchemarrow}{2}
\NewConfigure{mhchemarrowabove}{2}

\NewConfigure{mhchemarrowyields}{1}
\NewConfigure{mhchemarrowyieldsLeft}{1}
\NewConfigure{mhchemarrowyieldsLeftRight}{1}
\NewConfigure{mhchemarrowmesomerism}{1}
\NewConfigure{mhchemarrowequilibrium}{1}
\NewConfigure{mhchemarrowequilibriumRight}{1}
\NewConfigure{mhchemarrowequilibriumLeft}{1}

\Configure{mhchemarrow}{\HCode {<span~class="mhchem-arrow">}}{\HCode{</span>}}
\Configure{mhchemarrowabove}{\HCode { <span~class="mhchem-above">}}{\HCode{</span>}}
\Configure{mhchemarrowyields}{ \HCode { <span~class="mhchem-arrow-normal">&\#x27F6;</span> } }
\Configure{mhchemarrowyieldsLeft}{ \HCode { <span~class="mhchem-arrow-normal">&\#x2190;</span> } }
\Configure{mhchemarrowyieldsLeftRight}{ \HCode { <span~class="mhchem-arrow-normal">&\#x21c4;</span> } }  % todo: improve
\Configure{mhchemarrowmesomerism}{ \HCode { <span~class="mhchem-arrow-normal">&\#x2194;</span> } }  % todo: improve
\Configure{mhchemarrowequilibrium}{ \HCode { <span~class="mhchem-arrow-normal">&\#x21cc;</span> } }  % todo: improve
\Configure{mhchemarrowequilibriumRight}{ \HCode { <span~class="mhchem-arrow-larger">&\#x21c0;</span><span~class="mhchem-arrow-complement">&\#x21bd;</span> } }  % todo: improve
\Configure{mhchemarrowequilibriumLeft}{ \HCode { <span~class="mhchem-arrow-complement">&\#x21c0;</span><span~class="mhchem-arrow-larger">&\#x21bd;</span> } }  % todo: improve



\cs_set_protected:Npn \__mhchem_arrow_deployfourht:nnnnn #1#2#3#4#5
  {
    \a:mhchemarrow
    \tl_if_empty:nF {#3#5}
      {
        \a:mhchemarrowabove
        \str_case:nnF {#2}
          {
            {   } { \ce { #3 } }
            { M } { \ensuremath { #3 } }
            { T } { \text { #3 } }
            { C } { \ce { #3 } }
          }
          { \msg_error:nnn { mhchem } { unexpected-arrow-type } {#2} }
          \b:mhchemarrowabove
      }
    \str_case:nnF {#1}
      {
        { yields } {\a:mhchemarrowyields }
        { yieldsLeft } {\a:mhchemarrowyieldsLeft }
        { yieldsLeftRight } {\a:mhchemarrowyieldsLeftRight }  % todo: improve
        { esomerism } {\a:mhchemarrowesomerism }  % todo: improve
        { equilibrium } {\a:mhchemarrowequilibrium }  % todo: improve
        { equilibriumRight } {\a:mhchemarrowequilibriumRight }  % todo: improve
        { equilibriumLeft } {\a:mhchemarrowequilibriumLeft }  % todo: improve
      }
      { \msg_error:nnn { mhchem } { unexpected-arrow-type } {#1} }
    \tl_if_empty:nF {#3#5}
      {
        \a:mhchemarrowabove
        \str_case:nnF {#2}
          {
            {   } { \ce { #5 } }
            { M } { \ensuremath { #5 } }
            { T } { \text { #5 } }
            { C } { \ce { #5 } }
          }
          { \msg_error:nnn { mhchem } { unexpected-arrow-type } {#2} }
        \b:mhchemarrowabove
      }
    \b:mhchemarrow
  }

\HLet\__mhchem_arrow_deploy:nnnnn\__mhchem_arrow_deployfourht:nnnnn
  
\ExplSyntaxOff

% Additional configurations for MathML

% print mathml command or html, depending on if we are inside mathml or not
\newcommand\:mhmathmlorhtml[2]{\ifmathml\a:mathml #1\else #2\fi}
\newcommand\:mhonlyinmathml[1]{\ifmathml #1\fi}
\:CheckOption{mathml}
\if:Option

\Configure{mhchemcf}{\HCode{<\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span}\space class="mhchem-cf">}}{\HCode{</\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span}>}}
\Configure{mhchemce}{\HCode{<\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span}\space class="mhchem-ce">}}{\HCode{</\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span}>}}

\Configure{mhchemsub}{%
  \:mhmathmlorhtml{%
  \Send{BACK}%
  {<\a:mathml msub><\a:mathml mrow\Hnewline>}%
  \Tg</\a:mathml mrow>\Tg<\a:mathml mrow\Hnewline>\trap:base%
  }{%
  \HCode{<sub>}}%
}{\:mhmathmlorhtml{\Tg</\a:mathml mrow>\TG</\a:mathml msub\Hnewline>}{\HCode{</sub>}}}
\Configure{mhchemsup}{%
  \:mhmathmlorhtml{
  \Send{BACK}
  {<\a:mathml msup><\a:mathml mrow\Hnewline>}%
  \Tg</\a:mathml mrow>\Tg<\a:mathml mrow\Hnewline>\trap:base
  }{%
  \HCode{<sup>}}%
}{\:mhmathmlorhtml{\Tg</\a:mathml mrow>\TG</\a:mathml msup\Hnewline>}{\HCode{</sup>}}}

\Configure{mhchemoperator}{\HCode{<\:mhmathmlorhtml{mo}{span} class="mhchem-operator">}\PauseMathClass}{\EndPauseMathClass\HCode {</\:mhmathmlorhtml{mo}{span}>}}

\Configure{mhchemarrow}{\HCode {<\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span} class="mhchem-arrow">\:mhonlyinmathml{<mo>}}}{\HCode{\:mhonlyinmathml{</mo>}</\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span}>}}
\Configure{mhchemarrowabove}{\HCode { <\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span} class="mhchem-above">\:mhonlyinmathml{<mo>}}}{\HCode{\:mhonlyinmathml{</mo>}</\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span}>}}
\Configure{mhchemarrowyields}{ \HCode { <\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span} class="mhchem-arrow-normal">\:mhonlyinmathml{<mo>}&\#x2192;\:mhonlyinmathml{</mo>}</\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span}> } }
\Configure{mhchemarrowyieldsLeft}{ \HCode { <\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span} class="mhchem-arrow-normal">\:mhonlyinmathml{<mo>}&\#x2190;\:mhonlyinmathml{</mo>}</\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span}> } }
\Configure{mhchemarrowyieldsLeftRight}{ \HCode { <\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span} class="mhchem-arrow-normal">\:mhonlyinmathml{<mo>}&\#x21c4;\:mhonlyinmathml{</mo>}</\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span}> } }  % todo: improve
\Configure{mhchemarrowmesomerism}{ \HCode { <\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span} class="mhchem-arrow-normal">\:mhonlyinmathml{<mo>}&\#x2194;\:mhonlyinmathml{</mo>}</\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span}> } }  % todo: improve
\Configure{mhchemarrowequilibrium}{ \HCode { <\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span} class="mhchem-arrow-normal">\:mhonlyinmathml{<mo>}&\#x21cc;\:mhonlyinmathml{</mo>}</\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span}> } }  % todo: improve
\Configure{mhchemarrowequilibriumRight}{ \HCode { <\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span} class="mhchem-arrow-larger">\:mhonlyinmathml{<mo>}&\#x21c0;\:mhonlyinmathml{</mo>}</\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span}><\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span} class="mhchem-arrow-complement">\:mhonlyinmathml{<mo>}&\#x21bd;\:mhonlyinmathml{</mo>}</\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span}> } }  % todo: improve
\Configure{mhchemarrowequilibriumLeft}{ \HCode { <\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span} class="mhchem-arrow-complement">\:mhonlyinmathml{<mo>}&\#x21c0;\:mhonlyinmathml{</mo>}</\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span}><\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span} class="mhchem-arrow-larger">\:mhonlyinmathml{<mo>}&\#x21bd;\:mhonlyinmathml{</mo>}</\:mhmathmlorhtml{mrow}{span}> } }  % todo: improve
\else
\fi
% }

\Hinput{mhchem}
\endinput
```

There are still some extra HTML tags, you need to remove them using this configuration file, `config.cfg`:

```
\RequirePackage{color} 
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Configure{mhchemce}{}{}
\Configure{mhchemcf}{}{}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Compile using:

```
$ make4ht -c config.cfg -f odt Test.tex
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151091/discussion-on-answer-by-michal-h21-how-to-use-make4ht-for-threeparttable-with-si); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Is there somewhere info on what `tex4ht` adds to table cells? Testing with `collcell` (which uses a similar approach to `siunitx` to collect cell content), I find some additional tokens but also can't get even a simple collection to work.

Comment: @JosephWright I am afraid that it is in `latex.4ht`, probably around line 1145, where `\@array` is redefined. But as it is generated from literate sources, it is quite unreadable. Literate source is here: https://svn.gnu.org.ua/viewvc/tex4ht/trunk/lit/tex4ht-4ht.tex?view=log, around line 10190. The literate source format is described here: https://www.kodymirus.cz/tex4ht-doc/ForDevelopers.html#how-to-add-support-for-a-package-to-the-texht-literate-sources