# Combination of \cline and p-type column in table seems to break make4ht

Tags: tables, tex4ht, make4ht, cline

I am trying to convert a `.tex` file into `.odt` using `make4ht`. This is the MWE that is able to generate the error that I face:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{mode=text}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{p{2.8cm}
l
S[table-format=3.2(3)]
}

Compound & 
Sample & 
Start \\

\multirow{2}{=}{Cyanocobalamin} &
Tree 1 &
0.18(08) \\
\cline{2-3}
 &
Tree 2 &
4.10(168) \\
\cline{1-3}
\multirow{2}{=}{Retinol} &
Tree 1 &
0.21(37) \\
\cline{2-3}
 &
Tree 2 &
7.12(256)\\
\cline{1-3}
\multirow{2}{=}{4-methoxy\-cyclopentane} &
Tree 1 &
17.13(894) \\
\cline{2-3}
 &
Tree 2 &
12.05(12) \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

This code generates a pdf that looks like this:

[image: make4ht_cline]

I tried to convert this to a .odt file using the command: `make4ht -c config.cfg -f odt Test.tex` , but got the follow error:

```
[STATUS]  make4ht: Conversion started
[STATUS]  make4ht: Input file: Test.tex
[WARNING] domfilter: DOM parsing of Test.4oo failed:
[WARNING] domfilter: ...ive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaxml/luaxml-mod-xml.lua:175: Unbalanced Tag (/text:p) [char=4346]

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 75; columnNumber: 3; The element type "table:table-cell" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</table:table-cell>".
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1243)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:635)
    at java.xml/org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.parse(XMLFilterImpl.java:357)
    at xtpipes.Xtpipes.execute(Xtpipes.java:1300)
    at xtpipes.Xtpipes.execute(Xtpipes.java:783)
    at xtpipes.Xtpipes.mainMethod(Xtpipes.java:665)
    at xtpipes.Xtpipes.main(Xtpipes.java:70)
    at xtpipes.main(xtpipes.java:5)
--- xtpipes error 29 --- At <sax content-handler="xtpipes.util.ScriptsManager,tex4ht.OoFilter" lexical-handler="xtpipes.util.ScriptsManagerLH" > : While parsing file file:/home/aj/Documents/Testing_TeX-Odt/Only_Tables/Test.tmp: : org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 75; columnNumber: 3; The element type "table:table-cell" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</table:table-cell>".
[WARNING] xtpipes: Xtpipes failed

[WARNING] xtpipes: Trying HTML tidy
sh: 1: tidy: not found
[WARNING] xtpipes: Tidy failed as well
nil
[WARNING] domfilter: DOM parsing of Test.4oo failed:
[WARNING] domfilter: ...ive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaxml/luaxml-mod-xml.lua:175: Unbalanced Tag (/text:p) [char=4346]

[WARNING] odt: Cannot parse DOM, the resulting ODT file will be most likely corrupted
[STATUS]  make4ht: Conversion finished
```

As indicated in the last warning message, the `.odt` file indeed doesn't open.

## Notes

1. The error goes away if I removed the `\cline{}`, or changed the `p` into `l` in the tabular specifications. While this is an immediate fix, this isn't translatable to larger documents with complex tables.
2. Contents of the `config.cfg` and `siunitx.4ht` that were included to execute this command were taken from the answer of my previous questions: [How to use make4ht for threeparttable with siunitx to make an odt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/707485/how-to-use-make4ht-for-threeparttable-with-siunitx-to-make-an-odt)
3. I am on Linux Mint 21.3 with TeX 3.141592653 (TeX Live 2023) and kpathsea version 6.3.5.
4. I am using `make4ht` version v0.3m.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like another bug. Try this config file:

```
\RequirePackage{color} 
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Configure{mhchemce}{}{}
\Configure{mhchemcf}{}{}
\Configure{halignTD} {}{}
   {<}{\ifmathml \HCode{ columnalign="left"}\else
        L\fi}
   {-}{\ifmathml \HCode{ columnalign="center"}\else
        C\fi}
   {>}{\ifmathml \HCode{ columnalign="right"}\else
        R\fi}
   {^}{\ifmathml \HCode{ rowalign="top"}\else
        T\fi}
   {=}{\ifmathml \HCode{ rowalign="baseline"}\else
        N\fi}
   {|}{\ifmathml \HCode{ rowalign="center"}\else
        M\fi}
   {_}{\ifmathml \HCode{ rowalign="bottom"}\else
        B\fi}
   {p}{\ifmathml \HCode{ columnalign="left"}\else
        L\fi}
   {m}{\ifmathml\else m\fi}     %{\HCode{valign-middle   align-left}}
   {b}{\ifmathml\else n\fi}     %{\HCode{valign-baseline align-left}}
   {}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

`\Configure{halignTD}` is used to configure code for particular table preamble tokens. The code for `p` in the original version was empty, and in further processing of TeX4ht table processing code, it led to not inserting the starting element for a paragraph. Only a closing element was inserted, which led to this problem.

This is the result:

[image]

You can see another issue - the `start` column has the wrong formatting of numbers. This is caused by the fact that the `S` columns of Siunitx are not correctly supported. Hopefully, we will be able to fix this soon.